# Copying the value of a text field to another file's text field

Tags: javascript, function, asp-classic

I have a pop-up window from **file_A.asp** that has an input of a **text_field1**, Once the user key in the value of **text_field1** and click on **Save** button; it will redirect him to **file_B.asp** where the value written in **text_field1** is copied to a **text_field2** of **File_B.asp**

I know that it's impossible to copy a value of a text field from a file to another, that's why I need a JavaScript function to pass the value to the second file. but the thing is I don't know how to implement it.

Can some one please help me?

Comment: You can pass `input` value in `queryString`

Comment: Best approach would be to send the text_field1 to server when you're requesting for file_B.asp. On server change the value of text_field1 and then serve it. Apart from that if you want to keep things on client side, you can use cookies to achieve it. First page saves data in text_field1 in some cookie and second page reads this data from cookie.

Comment: localStorage or querystring

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your form attributes are set correctly...

```
<form id="main" method="post" target="form_b.asp">
    <input name="aField" type="text" />
```

...or...

```
<form id="main" method="get" target="form_b.asp">
    <input name="aField" type="text" />
```

...and...

```
Dim aField
aField = Request.Form("aField")
```

...or...

```
Dim aField
aField = Rquest.QueryString("aField")
```

Note: corrected to `name` attribute from `id`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try passing value of text_field1 using **URL** ?

Ex :

```
file_B.asp?val=VALUE_OF_TEXT_FIELD1
```

so you can get it like this ;

```
Request.QueryString("val")
```

Comment: You're almost there, but if the `form` method has been set correctly then it's just a case of using the correct `Request` - either `Request.QueryString` or `Request.Form`. Both have advantages and disadvantages.